# Laravel: how to pass GET array to controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, get, controller

How to pass array of GET parameters to the controller?

This is my route file `routes/web.php`:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Route::get('/ids', 'Parser@getIds');
```

And my controller 'app/Http/Controllers/Parser.php':

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Parser extends Controller
{
  public function getIds(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request); // ???
  } 
}
```

So, I expect to get an array of parameters like this:

```
$ids = [1,2,15,25];
```

But if I pass GET array to my route path: `http://example.com/ids?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=15&ids[]=25`

I get an empty request object anyway:

`{"attributes":{},"request":{},"query":{},"server":{},"files":{},"cookies":{},"headers":{}}`

Comment: The response is fine. The method json return a array encode to json. If you want just return the response. you can do it this: `return $request;` and this return you request.

Comment: I coded your example and it's working without any error or result is as expected.

Comment: @MAY appreciating your help. I don't know why but I had an empty `'request:{}'` object in json response as I described above. And then `$ids = request('ids', []);` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is few ways to get data from GET.
Try something like that:

```php
$ids = request('ids', []); // global helper, empty array as default
```

or:

```php
$ids = $request->input('ids', []); // via injected instance of Request
```

More info you can get [in documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request)

Comment: This is correct, but more specifically, it should be `request()->query('ids');` or `$request->query('ids')` if you are injecting the `Request` in the method. You can also pass a default value. `query('ids', [])`

Comment: request('ids') also works, but it is good notice to pass a default value. it will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much. `$ids = request('ids', []);` works well.